# .NET call web service return null in field defined as int

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl

I have a `Net` Application. I am consuming an external `WSDL`. the `XML` returned is like this,

```html
 <xsd:complexType name="DataOutput">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element name="ID2" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element name="EJEMPLAR" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
```

When I create the WSDL Reference, its creates a medatada `Class`

```
public class DataOutput
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }
    public string EJEMPLAR { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have is that fields `ID` and `ID2` can be `null`.

I can not change the Web Service, it is external so i can not handle it.

When I set

```
public string ID { get; set; }  
public string ID2 { get; set; }
```

But get me an error, that can not parse `int` not `null`

How can I manage from my side?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could define class com nullable types in .Net

For example  public int? ID{ get; set; }.

Comment: The problem is not how I define the class, the problem is the wsdl retrieving null in int type... If I define the class without int fields, when Wsdl parses to my class, it give me NO error, because it Wsdl int types are not retrieved... So, the problem is when It read int types is wsdl. The question should be, how to NOT parse when is null? Thanks